# OpenGL Drawing Spheres on click

Tags: python, opengl

I am trying to create a simple program, when you click it will draw a sphere at the mouse's location.

The issue is other a blank window nothing is displayed. In the code below I have at least confirmed that it registers the mouse clicks, and it is saving the mouse locations. I assume that the problem is somewhere in my display function, I'm just not sure where or why.

Most of what I did was based off of [this](http://www.de-brauwer.be/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=PyOpenGLHelloWorld) example.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from logging import warning
sphere_locations = [(0, 0)]

def init():                                            
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glPointSize(5.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)                              


def on_click(button, state, x, y):
    global sphere_locations
    if button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON and state == GLUT_DOWN:
        warning("CLICK")
        sphere_locations.append((x, y))


def display():
    global sphere_locations
    warning(sphere_locations)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)  
    for x, y in sphere_locations:
        glPushMatrix()                    
        glTranslatef(x, y, 1.0)    
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)         
        glutSolidSphere(0.3, 250, 250)   
        glPopMatrix()                    
    glFlush()                        
    glutSwapBuffers()                
    glutPostRedisplay()                



glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH )  
glutInitWindowSize(550, 550)
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50)
glutCreateWindow("Bubble Pop")  
glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutMouseFunc(on_click)
init()
glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: "the problem"...which is...what, exactly?  Is it deleting your home directory?  Bluescreening?

Comment: Woops sorry fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your coordinates maps incorrectly to the screen pixels (and mouse coordinates are given in screen pixels, starting from top/left). Also, `gluOrtho2D` defines a clipping region of depth from -1 to 1. Since we are using pixels here, your sphere would appear as a longitudinal slice of 2 pixel wide (just a ring). Using `glOrtho` instead of `gluOrtho2D` with the following parameters will fix both problems:

```
    glOrtho(0.0, 550.0, 550.0, 0.0, -100.0, 100.0);
```

this will make everything from depth -100.0 to 100.0 visible, which is more than enough to the spheres.

Second, your "spheres" are too small to be seen... since now we are working in pixels, increase their size to some pixels:

```
    glutSolidSphere(15, 250, 250)
```

They still don't look like spheres, because they lack gradual shading that gives the depth impression, but that is a lighting issue that is a much more complex topic.

Comment: Thanks that worked, as for the dotted thing, I have absolutely no clue, if you do find something please feel free to post again.